# Kick someone out connected to remote debug on weblogic

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic, remote-debugging, weblogic12c

I work with guys who sometimes work from home and may forget to disconnect their debugger from the server, which means that some of the calls we make get stuck on their break points and can't do anything about it unless I restart the server to force disconnect their debugger. This is an issue because it takes time for the server to be up and running

Is there any other way or command I can use to disconnect the other guys debugger without restarting weblogic?

Comment: You can try to run something like `tcpkill` to kill the debug port and hopefully disconnect whoever is remotely debugging... but it may lead to other issues. Worth a shot. http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/kill-tcp-connection-using-linux-netstat.php